# showing cannot open output file a.exe: Permission denied in visual studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, coding-style, permission-denied, ming

[earlier it was working fine in the same folder but now its not working , i restarted the pc also the also
any help will be great[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVQpS.png)

Comment: Your array has no nul terminator. So it isn't a C string, and `lengthOfString` has undefined behaviour. Has the executable crashed, or is still runnning?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As your IDE shows, your program is still running:

[image: evidence]

On Windows, the linker is not allowed to delete the executable file, if an application launched from it is still running.